# Execute 2 scripts in 1 page

Tags: javascript, php

Why does only second javascript execute and not the first one?
Maybe PHP also executs the second code only?

How can i execute both codes?

```html
<div id="anslut0"></div>
<div id="anslut1"></div>



<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://X.com/2.php');
echo $homepage;
?>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
if (document.getElementById("MixP0").innerHTML <= 5) { 
document.getElementById("MixP0").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("anslut0").innerHTML = "anslut0";
        } 
}
</script>


<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://X.com/3.php');
echo $homepage;
?>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
if (document.getElementById("MixP1").innerHTML <= 5) { 
document.getElementById("MixP1").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("anslut1").innerHTML = "anslut1";
        } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: probably overwriting onload function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute both, but both in a single `<script>` at the end.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        if (document.getElementById("MixP0").innerHTML <= 5) { 
            document.getElementById("MixP0").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("anslut0").innerHTML = "anslut0";
        } 
        if (document.getElementById("MixP1").innerHTML <= 5) { 
           document.getElementById("MixP1").style.visibility = "hidden";
           document.getElementById("anslut1").innerHTML = "anslut1";
        } 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Worked perfect!

Answer (score 3):

You set `window.onload` two times, so the second one overrides the first ! onload is called AFTER page has finished loading, not during the parsing of html.

Get familiar with addEventListener : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: What should i replace window.onload with?

Comment: @FastXXX see link provided. `addEventListener` applied to window with appropriate event name and callback.

Comment: Im reading about it right now but it seems hard for none coder. But im will try something hopefully.

Comment: Can even listener only listen to ''clicks''?

Comment: This explains the issue, but for extra credit, you should give an example of the `.addEventListener` which solves the users problem. This would have likely landed you with the green check mark, rather than the other (IMO lower quality answer).

Comment: I answered with a link to the reference, it's up to the user to have a look at the link and read the samples there. There's no point rewriting them here  again

Answer (score 1):

**Keep it Simple :)**. Create Two functions and call them from single `window.onload` event.

```
<div id="anslut0"></div>
<div id="anslut1"></div>

<?php
  $homepage = file_get_contents('http://X.com/2.php');
  echo $homepage;
?>

<script>
function first() {
  if (document.getElementById("MixP0").innerHTML <= 5) { 
    document.getElementById("MixP0").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("anslut0").innerHTML = "anslut0";
  } 
}
</script>

<?php
  $homepage = file_get_contents('http://X.com/3.php');
  echo $homepage;
?>

<script>
function second() {
  if (document.getElementById("MixP1").innerHTML <= 5) { 
    document.getElementById("MixP1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("anslut1").innerHTML = "anslut1";
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  first();
  second();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!